# jQuery with Service vb.NET (webmethod) non showing dmuy / MDTimePicker GitHub project

Tags: jquery, vb.net, timepicker, webmethod

I'm trying to use [dmuy / MDTimePicker github project](https://github.com/dmuy/MDTimePicker)
I add in my menu head some script, such as

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/mdtimepicker.js"></script>
```

And in my page

```
<li onclick="InserisciOrario('risultato','Inserimento Orario OneClick');"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>Inserisci Orario Trasferta</a></li>
```

To call a jQuery function "to go" to my webmethod that return string in a div to show clock

```
function InserisciOrario(div, tipo) {
  //var target = document.getElementById(div);
  ////var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
  $(div).html("");
  $.post({
    url: 'menu.aspx/CreaOrarioGiornaliero',
    type: 'POST',
    data: '{Tipo: "' + tipo + '" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
      document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = data.d;
      //spinner.stop();
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

Webmethod in vb.NET return a string in my div page

```
Html += "<tr><td colspan='4' style='text-align: center;'><div>Seleziona Inizio: <input type='text' id='InizioTrasferta'/></div><script>$(document).ready(function () {$('#InizioTrasferta').mdtimepicker();});</script>"
```

But nothing's shown.

If I put it in a standard HTML page it works.

Answer (score 1):

I put this function in app.js

```
function apritime() {
  $('#InizioTrasferta').mdtimepicker();
  $('#InizioTrasferta').show;
}
```

and call it from the method by onclick method

```
onclick=" + Chr(34) + "apritime();" + Chr(34) + "
```

<sub>*Answer added on behalf of OP.*</sub>